# Trying to tying the weights of the encoder and decoder layer but getting this unknown error for the Reshaping layer

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer, autoencoder

Trying to tying the weights of the encoder and decoder layer but getting this unknown error for the Reshaping layer. My tensorflow version is up to date, and I imported the layers from tensorflow.keras.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-6db796bd6af3> in <module>()
      7                             DenseTranspose(dense_2,activation="selu"),
      8                             DenseTranspose(dense_1,activation="sigmoid"),
----> 9                             keras.layers.Reshape([28,28])
     10 ])
     11 tied_ae = keras.models.Sequential([tied_encoder, tied_decoder])

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py in add(self, layer)
    176         layer = functional.ModuleWrapper(layer)
    177     else:
--> 178       raise TypeError('The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. '
    179                       f'Received: layer={layer} of type {type(layer)}.')
    180 

TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Received: layer=<__main__.DenseTranspose object at 0x7f207c95a690> of type <class '__main__.DenseTranspose'>.
```

Code to reproduce the error:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

class DenseTranspose():
  def __init__(self,dense,activation=None,**kwargs):
    self.dense = dense
    self.act_ = keras.activations.get(activation)
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  def build(self,batch_input_shape):
    self.biases = self.add_weight(name="bias",initializer="zeros",shape=[self.dense.input_shape[-1]])
    super().build(batch_input_shape)
  def call(self,inputs):
    z = tf.matmul(inputs,self.dense.weights[0],transpose_b=True)
    return self.act_(z + self.biases)
dense_1 = layers.Dense(100,activation="selu")
dense_2 = layers.Dense(30,activation="selu")
tied_encoder = keras.models.Sequential([
                           layers.Flatten(input_shape=[28,28]),
                           dense_1,
                           dense_2
])
tied_decoder = keras.models.Sequential([
                            DenseTranspose(dense_2,activation="selu"),
                            DenseTranspose(dense_1,activation="sigmoid"),
                            keras.layers.Reshape([28,28])
])
tied_ae = keras.models.Sequential([tied_encoder, tied_decoder])
tied_ae.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1.5), metrics=[rounded_accuracy])
history = tied_ae.fit(X_train, X_train, epochs=10,
                      validation_data=(X_valid, X_valid))
```

Comment: You forgot that your layer has to inherit from keras.layers.Layer

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer, as noted by Dr. Snoopy - the layer you created needs to inherit from keras.layers.Layer, so your class should start:

```py
class DenseTranspose(layers.Layer):
```

Your full code would then be:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

class DenseTranspose(layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self,dense,activation=None,**kwargs):
    self.dense = dense
    self.act_ = keras.activations.get(activation)
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  def build(self,batch_input_shape):
    self.biases = self.add_weight(name="bias",initializer="zeros",shape=[self.dense.input_shape[-1]])
    super().build(batch_input_shape)
  def call(self,inputs):
    z = tf.matmul(inputs,self.dense.weights[0],transpose_b=True)
    return self.act_(z + self.biases)
dense_1 = layers.Dense(100,activation="selu")
dense_2 = layers.Dense(30,activation="selu")
tied_encoder = keras.models.Sequential([
                           layers.Flatten(input_shape=[28,28]),
                           dense_1,
                           dense_2
])
tied_decoder = keras.models.Sequential([
                            DenseTranspose(dense_2,activation="selu"),
                            DenseTranspose(dense_1,activation="sigmoid"),
                            keras.layers.Reshape([28,28])
])
tied_ae = keras.models.Sequential([tied_encoder, tied_decoder])
tied_ae.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1.5), metrics=[rounded_accuracy])
history = tied_ae.fit(X_train, X_train, epochs=10,
                      validation_data=(X_valid, X_valid))
```